# WSL change the font and color for some applications (nano, tmux, vim)

Tags: windows, vim, screen, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using the WSL and I am having an issue because of the font. 
WSL has a font issue for CJK language, and I fixed it by editing the ubuntu terminal init file 
https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/757 

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\C:_ProgramFiles_WindowsApps_CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_xxxx.ubuntu.exe,
add CodePage->(DWORD)FDE9(65001)`

However, when I run some text editor such like `vim, emacs, nano`, or a terminal application like `tmux` or `screen`, **the WSL always change the font to the default font of Windows cmd**. Is there any way to prevent this?

- For additional information, when I run `echo $TERM` at my WSL, it produces `xterm-256color`, but when I run it in my tmux, it produces `screen`.
- I actually solved this problem last time for another computer, but I don't remember how I did it because I tried too many things. At least I know this is not impossible.

Comment: This seems a bug for wsl as discussed on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/177). I met the same problem. If what you want is a nice looking bash terminal. I found an alternative here ([wsl-terminal](https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal)) I think it works for me. You can right-click the title bar to change the font and the font is consistent when you open vim, tmux and nano. (I haven't test emacs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font of the WSL terminal easily by right-clicking on the title bar and clicking on properties. Then you click on the font tab and there you can change the font. If you want another font, install it in your Windows.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhLiO.png)

For tmux to display the correct colors of vim I set in my .vimrc `set termguicolors`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post links to screenshot/code/... as your answer should still be understandable in case the link becomes unavailable. Furthermore - how is "I don't know how to change the colour for tmux, I have been trying with no success." an answer?

Comment: I'm sorry for the screenshot link but I added it as a visual reference, it's not needed for my answer as I explain step by step how to do it. I edited my answer responding to the second question too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a too-late answer (like 4 years late), but I leave it anyway for someone who still finds the solution.

There was a solution where you create a new **registry key** for WSL. See bookyue's answer in this link; https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3988

> 1. Open regedit.
> 2. Find this. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\C:_Program Files_WindowsApps_CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2019.522.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc_ubuntu1804.exe (you will not as the same as mine)
> 3. then, add CodePage（Type: DWORD, Value: **0x01b5**).
>    It works for me!

You may need to search for a proper directory under `Console` if your WSL is not Ubuntu. Mine is Debian, and it worked too.

Also, make sure that you're creating the key for *the WSL version that you're currently using*. I found there are many versions installed on my desktop, probably by the Windows Updater, and the key gets ineffective when the Windows Updater installs a newer version. I assume Windows sets the current version automatically to the newest version, and in that case, you need to manually re-create the same key for the newer version to get it to work again.